# Rails Devise_token_auth invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, devise-token-auth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm building an api a restful based rails 5, devise_token_auth and Omniauth google Oauth2.

Currently basic account creation through email is working pretty well, Now I'm trying to configure Authentication with Google but during the authentication I'm facing to some errors that I'm not able to solve.

Below the different error I face:

```
Started GET "/omniauth/google_oauth2/callback?state=xxxxx&code=xxxxx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-24 20:57:55 +0800
I, [2018-04-24T20:57:55.496909 #14173]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
I, [2018-04-24T20:57:56.719943 #14173]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2018-04-24T20:57:57.074575 #14173] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: Code was already redeemed.
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed."
}
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"xxxxxxxx", "code"=>"xxxxxxx"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in
```

Or

```
Started GET "/omniauth/google_oauth2/callback?state=xxxxxx&code=xxxxxx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-24 21:13:46 +0800
I, [2018-04-24T21:13:46.268484 #14173]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
I, [2018-04-24T21:13:47.609079 #14173]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2018-04-24T21:13:47.978029 #14173] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Bad Request"
}
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"xxxxxx", "code"=>"xxxxxx"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in
```

Here also the configuration of:
devise.rb:

```
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 
                  'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',   
                  'client_secret',
                  provider_ignores_state: true,
                  :access_type => 'offline'
```

omniauth.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :google_oauth2, 
             'xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
             'client_secret',
             provider_ignores_state: true,
             :access_type => 'offline'
end
```

If you have any idea of the root cause, feel free to update it,

Comment: Which one is the error? "Code was already redeemed." OR "Bad request".

Comment: Finally I found the root cause,no need omniauth conf in devise.rb, plus I need to overload the function `assign_provider_attrs` from `OmniauthCallbacksController` in order to get the right attribute for my user

Comment: @Alexis: Can you post example about function `assign_provider_attrs `